# Поле type="email": как отключить проверку в html

Tags: html

В `input type="email"` как отключить проверку  `html`, что-бы не вылезало предупреждение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставить type=text ? Проверку браузером вы не отключите

Comment: а для подсказки можно использовать placeholder